# C++ scalar variable set to zero value

Tags: c++

I'm using CodeBlocks 13.12, g++ compiler and my local variables are all being initializated to 0.

I would to know if there's a way to avoid the compiler to set 0 to all my variables. I would like to have garbage value in them.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int a, b;
  cout << a << " " << b;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:
0 0

I don't want a and b to be zero. They should contain junk values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this case, even `0` is considered as garbage.

Comment: How do you define "garbage value"?

Comment: Yes, use a different compiler :). Really, it's undefined for a reason, if you want a value (e.g., 0xDEADCODE, 0xDEADBEEF are popular) then just set it. Note that any decent compiler should emit a warning that a and b are used before initialized.

Comment: If you don't set the value, the compiler is perfectly free to put anything it wants in there, including 0. You don't explain why you want these "junk values", but if you want something else you'll have to set it yourself.

Comment: it looks like author wants kind of random values, and that is not good idea to get them this way.

Comment: As Arkady says, I would like to get random values. Is it possible?

Comment: @ansimon Then ask how to get random or pseudo-random numbers?

Comment: @juanchopanza I don' want to get a random value. I want the variables not being initialized with a zero value. I researched that compiling with -O3 compiler flag would do the trick but it didn't.

Comment: @ansimon Your words: "*As Arkady says, I would like to get random values.*" Anyway, they aren't initialized. You are asking for something that can't be done.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks. I don't know why, same code in Windows shows junk values but in Linux, zero values.

Comment: @ansimon That's the thing with undefined behaviour, it is *undefined*. If you read an uninitialized value your program is broken/undefined/has no meaning and the compiler can do whatever it likes. Solution: don't do it.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler behaves differently in this regard when building with/without optimization. I'm guessing you are building without optimization and that's why the compiler zero initializes variables.

But, when that is said; don't go around reading uninitialized variables. That is undefined behaviour. While you may often just get a 'garbage' value, the compiler is actually free to generate whatever code it wants when it sees that your program is undefined. This includes not emitting any code at all,  emitting the code you expect as well as rewriting other parts of your program. *Don't* invoke undefined behaviour.

If you want a random value, use the `<random>` facilities - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random